# Dependency Injected Service Life and Concurrency Issues

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, dependency-injection, concurrency

I have a scenario for which I could not find exact answer/understanding. Consider there is a `IAccountService`, that has method `GenerateUniqueAccountNumber`. There is a window of few minutes *(let's say 10 minutes)* when a lot of users *(may be around 6K - 8K)* will be calling this method to generate their account number. This method will return a new number, based on counter value, maintained in db. Meaning, it will:

1. Get latest issued account number from db, maintained as counter. *(eg. 1000)*
2. Increment by one. *(eg. 1001)*
3. Assign the number to caller's account and save. *(some business logic)*
4. Set counter value (latest issued number) as 1001. So that next caller gets 1002.

**My question** is, how can I **guarantee the uniqueness** of the account number? I expect some **concurrent calls**. So is it good Idea to create a separate service `IAccountNumberManager` and move `GenerateUniqueAccountNumber` method inside it. And then register this service as `AddSingleton` lifetime? Registering it as `Singleton` would make any difference at all in this scenario?

OR

I should apply `lock` in concerned piece of code inside `IAccountService`, in order to guarantee, that concurrent requests get correct/sequenced account number?

OR

I should Do both? Meaning, create `IAccountNumberManager`, register it as `AddSingleton` lifetime, and also apply `lock` too?

Some technical explanation on it will be appreciated.

Comment: It's better to guarantee that uniqueness on the database side. That is database should provide you a value and increment it, not your code.

Comment: AutoIncrement would be usefull

Comment: @Evk No, because that is just an example. In reality, I have to do more than just increment to the number. that is why I have specified my questions explicitly.

Comment: Unless you have a requirement that there should be no gaps (say account number 1 followed by 3, with no 2 in between) - you can obtain and increment value from database at the same time, and THEN execute business logic with it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you will only ever have a single instance of your service running, then using a lock would be fine.

Unfortunately, having a singleton wouldn't help you here as you could still have two threads inside that method at once and you can get a classic read-modify-write race-condition:

```
Thread 1: Read counter (eg. 1000)
Thread 2: Read counter (eg. 1000)
Thread 1: Increment value
Thread 2: Increment Value
Thread 1: Write Value (eg. 1001)
Thread 2: Write Value (eg. 1001)
```

An alternative approach (still assuming you have a single instance) would be to use [Interlocked.Increment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.increment?view=net-5.0) to avoid the need for locking. This is an atomic increment operation which uses special features of the processor to ensure it doesn't run into the above race-condition.

However, if you are ever going to have to scale this service to have more than 1 instance running at the same time, you will have to use a different solution. Possible solutions here include:

1. As @Evk suggests, keep the ID allocation in the database where it handles all the concurrency for you
2. Allocate a block of account IDs to each instance e.g. Instance 1 reserves 1000-1999, instance 2 reserves 2000-2999 and they can then allocate independently from their reservations. This has the downside that the IDs aren't sequential but means you keep the allocation in your service.
3. Instead of using sequential integers, consider an alternative approach such as using GUIDs or namespaced-Ids where the ID includes the id of the instance allocating the ID